# How to set width to min-content but allow words to be on the same line?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I have a div that contains text, but there is empty space around them by default. Setting the width to min-content solves this, but it means that each word will be on a separate line. If there is space for more than 1 word on 1 line, I need the words to stay be on one line.

Here is what things look like with without `width: min-content`:

[image]

As you can see, there is space around this for some reason and I can't figure out why. It's just a grid item/flex item and no css a part from font size and line height.

Comment: add `white-space: nowrap;` to your element.

Comment: I want the words to wrap if they're not going to fit. I just don't want the space around them

Comment: ok, can you provide a snippet code? In this way we can check what's the reason of the space around?

Comment: Because of the way the code is, I can't really get a snippet :(

Comment: maybe try to reproduce the issue with minimal code ..

Answer (score 0):

You can give reffer below code for achieving this.

You can try using `white-space: pre-wrap;` or `white-space: nowrap;` for your case

```
.my-text{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

or

```
.my-text{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You can reffer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: Pre-wrap just put everything on one line, which overflowed out of the div

Comment: can you please update your quetion with the code so we can take a look and give you a proper solution

Answer (score 0):

I think `max-width: fit-content;` is what you need.